# How to handle DST in the postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone

My default time zone is US/Eastern and I am trying to convert date time in the UTC.

For e.g I am using the following query that convert ET to UTC

```
SELECT '2019-12-10 03:00:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Output: "2019-12-10 08:00:00" which is correct.

But same thing I was try during the DST time then it won't work.

```
SELECT '2019-03-10 02:00:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';

SELECT '2019-12-10 03:00:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Output for above two query is : "2019-03-10 07:00:00"

I was expected that only 4 hours is added into the time so 1st query output would be '2019-03-10 06:00:00' and 2nd query output would be "2019-03-10 07:00:00"

But due to same output of two query function is not behave correctly.

I am using the postgressql 10.14.1

Thanks in advance for support.

Comment: There was no 02:00:00 in US/Eastern on 10 March 2019.  The clocks moved from 01:59:59 to 03:00:00 for DST.  GIGO.

Comment: Thanks @MikeOrganek your reply is work for me